# Scrollview change subview order using touch move or any other

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I am trying to change subview order in `scrollview`. First image is scroll view. Second image is if user touch and hold on Page #1(Which is `UIButton`) and go to down that time `scrollview` look like this. Third image is if user down that time and if user touch end that time my Page #1 button order is three

[image]   [image]    [image]    [image]

Comment: may be scrollview content size is proper

Comment: For this , There is better approach by using tableView, if you want vertical scrolling because in uitableview we can drag cells in edit mode property

Comment: @kshitijgodara godara can you give me any link of how to do that using uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link and look for moving of cells section in this link

[http://www.colejoplin.com/2012/10/05/ios-tutorial-editing-tableviews/][1]

I think this will surely going to help in reordering but if still not then you can search on Reordering of cells in uitableview .